# Database Script for moodle

Tags: sql, sql-server, model-view-controller

I am currently working to develop a moodle and I was looking for SQL scripts (not my sql ) for my database.
I have tried but I could not find. I already visited the following pages:

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Database_Schema

and

https://support.chamilo.org/documents/57

but did not get any script. can you provide me some scripts for a moodle, in SQL Microsoft?Thanks

Comment: Where is the question? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you just looking for some example queries to the SQL database, like these ones?
 https://docs.moodle.org/33/en/ad-hoc_contributed_reports#User_and_Role_Report